# Replace text in multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I am a C++ developer trying to convert something to VBA to replace a call to a legacy ActiveX control.

We have over 100 spreadsheets that rely on an ActiveX control written about 20 years ago. The call into this ActiveX control is creating a strange failure on some Laptops and crashing the code. Research suggests that ActiveX is best replaced. Having re-written the code into a .Bas file I have the problem of applying it to all the legacy spreadsheets.

I am attempting to automate the following:

1. Open the spreadsheet
2. Remove "UserForm1" - this is where the ActiveX instantiates and seems better to remove the form
3. Import the file "Dongle.bas"
4. Replace the line of code UserForm1mpg1prefectdongle1.CheckSTCLDongle(9, True)" with "Dongle.CheckDongle()". The offending line of code is in the object "ThisWorkbook"
5. Close the worksheet but add a password to protect the VBA code

Note - in some of the spreadsheets there is a password but I do know the password.

I attempted to record a Macro to at least be able to automate the steps once a spreadsheet is opened but I cannot find a way to replace the code snippet. I have found a command to import the .bas file but when I run the macro it did not seem to import it to the spreadsheet I have open.

Comment: Since a lot of your steps represent actions undertaken in the VBA editor I'd suggest reading [this](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx) article.

Comment: When you say 'there is a password', what is the password protecting exactly? eg does the password prevent opening the Workbook entirely? Or protects editing the content of the Workbook? Or protects the VBA Project (ie in the VBE ... the Visual Basic Editor)?

Comment: Hi JohnM. It is the VBE that is password protected. So you only need the password if you press the VisualBasic button. I have managed to complete all the steps now - found an article that showed how to loop through a folder of XLS files. The only thing I cannot resolve is how to open the VBE and update the code if it is protected. I am not trying to crack the password. I can unlock in manually. I am just trying to open the VBE programmatically to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manually unprotect all workbooks, this code will change the contents of the module, import the dongle code and remove the userform.
Instead of "ActiveWorkbook", use the object variable of the opened workbook.

Before you open a number of workbooks from vba, set calculation to manual to speed up the process: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

`Application.EnableEvents = False` will also help to avoid running code when you open the workbooks

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveUserForm1()
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")
End Sub

Sub ImportBasModule()
    ' right click the module and choose export to save it as Dongle.bas
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\temp\Dongle.bas"
End Sub

Sub ModifyThisWorkbook()
    Dim i As Integer, arr() As String, sTemp As String, iLine As Integer
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
        arr = Split(.CodeModule.Lines(1, .CodeModule.CountOfLines), vbCrLf)
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print arr(i)
            If InStr(arr(i), "UserForm1mpg1prefectdongle1.CheckSTCLDongle(9, True)") > 0 Then
               arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), "UserForm1mpg1prefectdongle1.CheckSTCLDongle(9, True)", "Dongle.CheckDongle()")
            End If
        Next
        .CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, .CodeModule.CountOfLines
        iLine = 1
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            .CodeModule.InsertLines iLine, arr(i)
            iLine = iLine + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```